# Non--homeomorphic manifolds-with-boundary having homeomorphic boundaries?

Tags: manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

What is a simple example of two topological $n$-manifolds-with-boundary $M$ and $N$ that are *not* homeomorphic yet whose boundaries $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: (A) A disk and a mobius band. (B) A disk and a punctured torus. (c) A circle union a line segment, and a line segment. Many more.

Comment: (c) is OK, but I guess I really wanted $M$ and $N$ to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

Poke a (large-ish) hole in a sphere and a torus ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be any compact topological $n$-manifold with boundary, and $L$ be any compact topological $n$-manifold without boundary. Then $K$ and $K \cup L$ have the same boundary, but different numbers of components, so they're not homeomorphic.

Comment: OK, but I guess I really wanted the manifolds-with-boundary to be connected (although I failed to so stipulate).

Comment: OK. Well, then you learned something about writing questions, and my first two examples in my comment provide connected cases. For $L$ being anything but a sphere, you can just take a connected sum rather than a disjoint union of $K$ and $L$, and the result's likely to not be homeomorphic to $K$ anyhow.